# Chat links and links to site from chat inconsistent behaviour

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

In the top right menu where you can access the chat of the Stack Exchange site you're on, the link doesn't open a new window.

[image: Picture of the top right menu link]

While once in the main chat room of the site, if you click on the link to the site it does open a new window.

[image: Picture of link to main site from chat]

I think this is kind of an inconsistent behaviour, and I would love to see the link in the menu opening a new tab. What do you think about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

balpha gives the reasoning for links opening in new tab in [this answer to a related feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130507/152859):

> The reason for links that take you somewhere else (i.e. not just to a different room) being opened in a new tab is simply that if we opened it in the same tab, that essentially means you're leaving the chat, which is probably not your intention.

So while being indeed inconsistent with links around Stack Exchange (which open in the same tab/window), this reason is enough to justify the difference.

Comment: I disagree most of the time i want to open both the chat and stackechange and end up with using back and midclick. well I think i will have to deal with that. thank you